# gzip base64 encode and decode string on both linux and windows

Tags: base64, gzip

I have a encoded string which was encoded using below command on linux machine,

```
cat <file-name> | gzip | base64 -w0
```

And I am able to decode and string using below method,

```
echo '<encoded-string> | base64 -di | zcat
```

Is there any way to decode the same string on windows machine.

Comment: This question is worth it for the useful linux one-liners alone! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method:

```
echo VERY_LARGE_STRING | gzip | base64 -w0
```

.. is limited by linux setting :

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

Used the below and saved my day. Many thanks to Karthik1234

```
cat <file-name> | gzip | base64 -w0
```

**Here is how we unzip in C# the message compressed in linux**
**Note:** You may need to remove the last byte.

```
static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip)
{
    // Create a GZIP stream with decompression mode.
    // ... Then create a buffer and write into while reading from the GZIP stream.
    using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip),
    CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        const int size = 4096;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                if (count > 0)
                {
                memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            return memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how a solution in C# answers the question? I presume the author was looking for a similar command line solution.